# Display full name of all properties of an object

Tags: c#, recursion, reflection

I have two class :

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public bool isActif { get; set; }

    public Quantity Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Quantity
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

And one method who display all properties of one instance of my class Customer with Reflection and Recursion :

```
public static void DisplayProperties(object objectA)
{
    if (objectA != null)
    {
        Type objectType;

        objectType = objectA.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.CanRead))
        {
            object valueA = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectA, null);

            if (typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType) || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "." + propertyInfo.Name);
            }
            else
                DisplayProperties(valueA);
        }
    }
}
```

The result :

```
Customer.FirstName
Customer.LastName
Customer.Date
Customer.isActif
Quantity.Color
Quantity.Number
```

But I want to recover the full name of property like that

```
Customer.FirstName
Customer.LastName
Customer.Date
Customer.isActif
Customer.Quantity.Color
Customer.Quantity.Number
```

How to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `DisplayProperties` method to this

```
public static void DisplayProperties(object objectA, string objName="")
{
    if (objectA != null)
    {
        Type objectType;

        objectType = objectA.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.CanRead))
        {
            object valueA = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectA, null);

            if (typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType) || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(objName +  (objName==""? "" : ".") + propertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "." + propertyInfo.Name);
            }
            else
                DisplayProperties(valueA, objName + (objName == "" ? "" : ".") + objectType.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach will be to pass the path with every call for `DisplayProperties`.

Change the method signature:

```
public static void DisplayProperties(object objectA, string path = "")
```

Change the printing method

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}.{2}", path, propertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name, propertyInfo.Name);
```

Change the recursive calling method

```
DisplayProperties(valueA, objectA.GetType().Name + ".");
```